# Locating ggts.ini in MAC

Tags: eclipse, grails

Where can I locate `ggts.ini` file in MAC. I know command, but cant find the file.

Comment: @dmahapatro Yes first place I looked at. Unable to find. Any alternate solution please!

Comment: Actually this is correct, depending on how you install it on a Mac you get the file or you don't. I don't use a Mac but have seen this before with a coworker. IIRC he copied one from another similar Mac and edited that. My advice is to upgrade to Linux.

Comment: Thanks @BurtBeckwith. I gotta find out an alternate solution.

Comment: My bad. I did not see it was mentioned as MAC os.

Comment: If this is the ggts equivalent of eclipse.ini then it's probably inside the GGTS.app bundle - ctrl-click, show package contents, then navigate to Contents/MacOS

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks! Exactly what i wanted. Found it.

Comment: OK, good guess on my part then :-)  I've made my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the GGTS equivalent of `eclipse.ini` then it's probably inside the `GGTS.app` bundle - ctrl-click, "show package contents", then navigate to `Contents/MacOS` inside the bundle.